# Error when checking target: expected dense_21 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2300, 4, 54)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have a problem which deals with predicting four outputs when given a vector of predictors. It is throwing an error at the LSTM layer input.

I have

```
X.shape,Y.shape = ((2300, 36, 768), (2300, 4, 54))


# Core Part

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}-{acc:03f}-{val_acc:03f}.h5', verbose=1, monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')  

data_dim = 768
timesteps = X.shape[1]
num_classes = 10


# # expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim))) 
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(32)) 

model.add(Dense(54, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1)
```

The Above code is working fine when i have `X.shape,Y.shape = ((2300, 36, 768), (2300, 15))`

How can i overcome from this, and How can i set LSTM and DENSE layes if i have more then one, four or ten prediction output?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your output is not a sequence, you could make use of `Reshape` layer as follows:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Reshape, Dense, Activation
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(100, 32))) 
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(32))

# now we have a vector of length 32 and
# we want the dense layer to have 4*54=216 neurons so that
# we will be able to reshape it to a matrix of shape (4, 54) in
# the next (Reshape) layer.
model.add(Dense(4*54))
model.add(Reshape((4, 54)))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()
```

which will print:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100, 256)          295936    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 100, 64)           82176     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                12416     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 216)               7128      
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 4, 54)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 4, 54)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 397,656
Trainable params: 397,656
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution @Bashir. Could you please explain it in details, why you take model.add(Dense(4*54))
model.add(Reshape((4, 54))) ??

Comment: I added comments regarding the dense and reshape layer

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to get *4* outputs, your final `Dense` layer should have *4* neurons and not *54*, i.e.,

`model.add(Dense(54, activation='softmax'))`

should be:

`model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))`

Also, your *Y* should have a shape of `(number_of_examples, 4)`, in your case it should be

`(2300, 4)` 
instead of
`(2300, 4, 54)`

If you actually have a *Y* with a shape of `(2300, 4, 54)`, then you cannot use a `Dense` layer at the output as `Dense` layer only works with examples that are one-dimensional vectors each.

Comment: So any alternative to do this??

Comment: Added an answer separately

Comment: Tanks Bashir, Can you explain why you added model.add(Dense(4*54))
model.add(Reshape((4, 54))), i need to know. its Working fine as you mentioned.